# How do I keep my laptop fan on?

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling, overheating

My Toshiba laptop is completely dusted out and I keep it on a dinner plate to keep a consistent air flow. The problem is the fan stops. I know that it is supposed to turn on when needed but it doesn't do that... at least not when I need it the most.

When the fan stops my core temp rose to 100 Degrees... and the fan still would not turn on, and thus the computer shut down.

I have speedfan but it isn't exactly user friendly... all I want is an option that allows me to turn on the fan and KEEP it on. I went into my BIOS and could not any fan options.

Comment: Power it off, pop the battery out to be sure all circuits are dead, and blow the dust out with an air bottle, compressor (take care not to dislodge anything - those critters are powerful), or vacuum cleaner (again, take care). That always worked for me. If the fan doesn't turn on at 100 °C, however... either the thermal sensor is busted, or the fan is. If you're lucky, the fan is simply clogged externally, and a good air blow will make it work again. If you are less lucky, it's clogged internally and has to either be disassembled, cleaned and lubricated, or (better) replaced altogether.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a dying fan.  Why not take it in to a shop and get a new one installed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a 'laptop cooling pad'? A laptop cooling pad generally has two or more constant fans that would help to keep your laptop cool, and they are relatively inexpensive.

Comment: The fan does work, but turns on and off intermittently, I just find it odd that it would not turn on when the core got really hot. I was hoping to find a way to keep the fan on contently, but I guess I really will need to get one of those cooling pads after all.

Comment: I'd suggest you also consider Iserni's answer - give that a try, failing that, listen to Techie007's advice, and take it along to a PC repair shop and see how much they would charge to have a look at it for you. A cooling pad 'may' be cheaper and solve the overheating problem, but it would reduce the mobility of the laptop, having to carry a cooling pad, as well as the laptop.